# How to reset append() on modal? I'm using NODE JS and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

The `append()` calls below append HTML every time I click the modal. If I try to use `empty()` or `html()` then the modal doesn't appear anymore. What is the correct way to create this modal?

```
function indivview(id)
{
    $('#indivformModal').modal("show"); 
    var data = {};
    data.id = id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/indiv',                     
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.AGE);
            console.log(data.SEX);
            $('#indivformslist').append("<a href='http://localhost:3000/legone/survey/surveyform/save/f41'><br> FORM 4.1 </a>");
            /* additional $('#indivformslist').append() calls */
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the answer and it is very simple. Sorry for asking this question!

```js
$('#indivformslist').empty();
```

Comment: If this is your answer, please mark this question as answered.